# C how could an unsigned int only takes two bytes?

Tags: c, struct, hex, offset, memory-address

I'm playing around with pointers and I've noticed one weird thing.

I have a struct as follow:

```
typedef struct list_element_struct {
    uint32_t x; 
    uint32_t y; 
    uint32_t z; 
    struct list_element_struct *next; 
    }list_element;
```

As far as I know, the size of unsigned int is 4 bytes, and the size of a pointer is 8 bytes. Also there are 8 bytes aligned happened here so the size of this struct is 24 bytes.

I've initialized a list of above struct objects with `list_element els[5];` and also set every piece of data in there to 0 with `memset(els,0,5*sizeof(list_element));`

Right now I'm trying to see their memory locations with these piece of code:

```
printf("%p start location of els\n", &(els));
printf("%p start location of els->x\n", &(els->x));
printf("%p start location of els->y\n", &(els->y));
printf("%p start location of els->z\n", &(els->z));
printf("%p start location of els->next(pointer)\n", &(els->next));
printf("%p start location of els+1\n", &(els[1]));
```

What I have as printed out is:

```
0x7ffeeba4a970 start location of els
0x7ffeeba4a970 start location of els->x
0x7ffeeba4a974 start location of els->y
0x7ffeeba4a978 start location of els->z
0x7ffeeba4a980 start location of els->next(pointer)
0x7ffeeba4a988 start location of els+1
```

Here is the weird thing. Why does els->z only takes two bytes? it really should take 4 like x and y.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` has to be at least one, that's literally the only restriction. It's often 4, but no guarantees. The same goes for pointers, except that nowadays 8 is also a common size.

Comment: Have a look at `0x7ffeeba4a988`. There are some indications that there are more digits than 0-9 ;)

Comment: ... `0x77` `0x78` `0x79` `0x7a` `0x7b` `0x7c` `0x7d` `0x7e` `0x7f` `0x80` `0x81` ...

Comment: "As far as I know, the size of unsigned int is 4 bytes, and the size of a pointer is 8 bytes." --> is one of many possibilities.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those numbers are hexadecimal.  The difference between `0x7ffeeba4a978` and `0x7ffeeba4a980` is not 2 but 8.

To forestall your next question, the reason it's 8 and not 4 is likely due to alignment requirement.  Many 64-bit systems either require or prefer to align their 8-byte pointers to 8-byte boundaries, i.e. to addresses which are a multiple of 8 (so that their least-significant hex digit is either `8` or `0`).  So the compiler leaves 4 bytes of padding between `z` and `next` to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The addresses are displayed as hexadecimal values

```
0x7ffeeba4a978 start location of els->z
0x7ffeeba4a980 start location of els->next(pointer)
```

So (considering the last two hexadecimal digits) you have

```
  0x80
-
  0x78
  ====
     8
```

because `0x80` is equal to `0x70` + decimal `16` or hex `0x10`.

Hexadecimal digits in the acsending order are

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F and the next number is 0x10.
```

The compiler placed a padding equal to 4 bytes after the data member `z` for alignment.